# Why does assigning short to byte only work when the short is final?

Tags: java

Can someone please explain why the following compiles:

```
final short s1 = 1;
final char c1 = 1;
byte b1 = s1;
byte b2 = c1;
```

But the following doesn't (the compiler error message is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from short to byte`):

```
short s1 = 1;
char c1 = 1;
byte b1 = s1;
byte b2 = c1;
```

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from short to byte

Comment: @balalaika I guess he understands that he can cast. He asking why the first 4 lines do not cause a problem for the compiler.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The answer is in the [JLS - 5.2. Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> .. if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type `byte`,
>   `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if
>     the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the
>     constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

When you write:

```
final short s1 = 1;
```

The value of the expression is *known* at compile time, and since it cannot be changed you don't need to cast.

In your second snippet, the value is not known at compile time - it's evaluated in *runtime*, so you'll need an explicit cast.

---

If you try to compile the following code:

```
final byte b1 = 200;
final byte b2 = 200;
byte sum = b1 + b1;
```

You'll get a *compilation* error since the values at the right side are *known* to the compiler and it knows that the sum cannot fit into a `byte`.

Answer (score 17):

In the first sample, the compiler knows that `s1` and `c1` will never change, and that their final value (`1`) fits into `byte`.

In the second, the compiler worries what would happen if `s1` and `c1` were outside <strike>`0..255`</strike> `-128..127` when they were assigned to a `byte` variable, and warns you that it is unsafe.

If you explicitly cast them as balalaika suggests in comments, the compiler is relieved that you seem to know what you're doing (or at least, that it has someone to blame if things go south), and lets you do it.

Comment: Amazing! Can you point to explanation about this 'feature' in JLS?

Comment: Can you also explain why this: `final long s1 = 1; int x = s1;` doesn't work?

Comment: I can't. The trivial explanation is: the JLS only allows it for `byte`, `short`, `char` and `int` (awesome find, Maroun Maroun - +1!). However,  but does not provide any explanation for it, or for the omission of `long`. My explanation makes sense to me; but I can't figure out why `long` is not allowed to behave in the same way.